# Android Studio: run/debug release version of app

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, release

I have added gradle build to Android app, and can launch from Android Studio.
`gradlew build` produces debug and released (signed, minified with proguard) versions.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        zipAlignEnabled true
        versionNameSuffix "-" + buildDateTime()
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        // Eclipse project.properties # proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        zipAlignEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        versionNameSuffix "-" + buildDateTime()
    }
```

But when I `adb install` on device the release version it crashes on start.

**How can I run/debug release version of app from Android Studio to find exact place of problem?**

Or can I debug manually released signed apk in Eclipse?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There's a window called 'Build Variants' where you can choose, which version you want to be installed on your emulator/device.

[image]

You also have to add `debuggable true` to your release build to be able to debug it.

Comment: BTW must add `debuggable true` for release buildType see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types

Comment: Yes, I missed that aspect, Android Studio only adds that for the debug builds.

Comment: More exactly those are defaults defined in android gradle plugin, not IDE

Comment: Well, I can run, but I cannot debug: `Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse`  and
`Waiting for process: com.company.app  `.
On devise side there is dialog "Waiting for debugger to connect" :-(

Comment: That window is empty for me. No values are listed

Comment: in .kts file :   isDebuggable =  true

Answer (score 12):

**Android Run .apk**

```
View -> Tool Windows -> Build Variants
```

Additionally you can use `Gradle` toolbar or `./gradlew tasks --all`

```
//install on device(which is running)
Tasks -> install -> install<build_varaiant>

//open 
adb shell am start -n <package_name>/.<activity_name>
```

*Android Studio v4.2 does not contain `Tasks` by default. You should disable `Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync` in `Preferences -> Experimental`

Comment: Basically shorter version of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Profile or Debug APK option in android studio and debug your release apk.

[image]

Comment: this options showed me an error on my debugabble release build that wasn't shown before. In my case I had to download and install a new skd version