# How to merge two different projects that are already in playstore using flavors

Tags: android, google-play, android-productflavors

The problem i am facing is there is two project(apps) similar and there will be more in future and when i change a code in one i will need to do same changes in other projects. when i searched on web i found product flavors but not sure if it's the answer for my problem.

How can i merge two different projects (apps) in playstore. Projects codes are %85 similar can i use flavors to merge both project in one and will i be able to update them in playstore using different jks with different package names and a few different permissions. Will i need AndroidManifest file for each flavor.

How can i solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194748/different-keystore-for-different-product-flavors-in-gradle  Another option might be to move the common code to a library project which you then use in both apps.

Comment: @Michael hi thanks for the answer do you know if it will be enough to update app using its applicationId or does google playstore need something else in the new flavor based project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **To change packageName you have to create product Flavor like**

```
flavorDimensions "versionCode"

productFlavors {

    doctorApp {
        dimension "versionCode"
        applicationId  "com.doctor.app"

    }
    patientApp {
        dimension "versionCode"
        applicationId  "com.patient.app"
    }
}
```

After that create two sibling folder of main after switch project View to Project

```
app -> src -> main       /// write all common classes here
app -> src -> doctorApp  // doctor related classes here along with their resources
app -> src -> patientApp // patient related classes here along with their resources
```

create same `package name` and `res folder` under **patientApp** and **doctorApp**